# Crop Image in specific shape Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an `UIImageView* shape` which is in fixed position. Behind that view I have another view which I can move, scale and rotate with gestures. I would like when I finish with customising the view behind the "shape" to press a button crop and crop the image. You can see  video here of what exactly I am trying to do.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CTNGire1gQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask one image with another image to get custom shape image. See tutorial to get some idea about masking

**http://www.raywenderlich.com/4421/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-1-0**